# How do I omit the html extension in next.js?

Tags: next.js

I'm building a static site using next.js, and I want my `website.com/about.html` to work just as: `website.com/about` -- I'm not sure why it's forcing me to type `.html`.

Even if I structure my project: `pages/about/index.js` -- it generates a `about.html` instead of `about/index.html` on the static site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with NextJS exporting files with .html extension but in<Link> there is no .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867105/how-to-deal-with-nextjs-exporting-files-with-html-extension-but-inlink-there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on next's website:

```
module.exports = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash

Comment: This works, but there is an issue: When the user types no trailing slash, there is a redirect to the URL with the slash. That redirect costs time, in particular in high-latency scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

You can use it if you have NEXT.JS 9.5 or higher versions.

Take a look at this NEXT.JS official document.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash