# How to deal with NextJS exporting files with .html extension but in<Link> there is no .html

Tags: javascript, next.js

So, I have a NextJS application and the way I have been building links is through  component. For eg: `<Link href="/my-page"><a>My page</a></Link>`. I have built the whole app with this pattern for  However, when I did an export to generate a static site, it created the out folder with pages with .html extension. This is now a problem, since, say a link might be pointing to `/my-page` but the actual page is `/my-page.html`. What's the right way of handling this issue? Does NextJS allows us to do anything in this situation or do I need to go back and code all my  tags using `/my-page.html` links?

Thanks.

Comment: Try following my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62842209/1174966) and see if that works for you

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13806

Answer (score 35):

The default in next.js for static generation is to map this code:

```
/pages/p1.tsx
```

to this file:

```
/p1.html
```

The problem with that is that a link to /p1 will work when you use the next server, and will fail when you're serving static files.

If you enable this, in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {trailingSlash: true,}
```

Then you'll get a different file:

```
/p1/index.html
```

And on most generic web servers (Apache out of the box, for example), you get this behavior:

```
/p1 - redirects to /p1/
/p1/ - serves /p1/index.html
/p1/index.html - serves /p1/index.html
```

So I think `module.exports = {trailingSlash: true,}` gets you the behavior you're expecting.

(@jdaz's link to the other answer is definitely useful for this, but that question was very specifically about configuring .htaccess, so I'm repeating a similar answer here)

Comment: `module.exports = {trailingSlash: true,}` produces 

`Error occurred prerendering page "/auth/restore". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
`

Comment: This mostly shifts the complexity of the solution to the (web) serving logic. Is there not a native (Next.js) solution?