# Next.JS links do not work after exporting static HTML

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am new to NEXT.JS and I am having some trouble deploying a static site. I have a component `Nav.tsx` that looks like this:

```
const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <nav className='nav p-3 border-bottom'>
            <Link href='/' passHref>
                <a className='pointer my-auto h2'>Blog </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/about' passHref>
                <a className='ms-5 pointer lead my-auto'>Who We Are</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/services' passHref>
                <a className='ms-5 pointer lead my-auto'>Services</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/contact' passHref>
                <a className='ms-5 pointer lead my-auto'>Contact</a>
            </Link>
        </nav>
    );
};
export default Nav;
```

When I run my development server locally, I can use those links to navigate around my site. But when I build, using `next build && next export` the links do not work for navigation. All of those links (`/about`, `/services`, `/contact`) are files in my `pages` directory. Have I written something incorrect in `Nav.tsx`, or am I misunderstanding how NEXT works? Thank you!

Comment: _"the links do not work for navigation"_ - can you be more specific? Does nothing happen when you click a link? Do you get a 404 instead?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens when you click a link.

Comment: Do you see any request 404ing in the Dev tools Network tab? Or any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2022-02-14

This can be solved by applying `{trailingSlash: true}` inside the `next.config.js`. See [How to deal with NextJS exporting files with .html extension but in<Link> there is no .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867105/how-to-deal-with-nextjs-exporting-files-with-html-extension-but-inlink-there) for details.

### Original answer (which does NOT work)

I encountered the same problem very recently and found out that this can be solved by moving other non-index pages such as `pages/search.js` into `pages/search/index.js`. No need for hacking via `.htaccess` and so on.

However, you'll need to update your relative imports so Next.js will still be able to compile, such as:

```js
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
```

to

```js
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';
```

Comment: So if I have a component like this one that I reuse, it would have a path like `pages/nav/index.tsx`. wouldnt that mean if I went to /nav it would show just this small reusable component? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: In this case, `nav.tsx` is simply a component so you don't need to convert it into `pages/nav/index.tsx`. You only need to convert those TSX files which are responsible for `/about`, `/services`, and `/contact` pages, which should be `pages/about.tsx`, `pages/services.tsx`, and `pages/contact.tsx` respectively.

Comment: ah, so I will have `pages/index.tsx`, and hten `pages/contact/index.tsx` for everywhere I want to link to.

Comment: ^^ that did not work unfortunately.

Comment: I've updated the answer, and apparently you don't need to move `pages/about.tsx` to `pages/about/index.tsx` and so on.