# How to add a page route with html extension on nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I need to convert a non-nextjs page to nextjs. In order to not lose my SEO ranking, I have to create the route with html extension. To make the picture look better, I am adding the folder structure down below.

[image]

Unfortunately, this route ending up as 404 on the browser.

[image]

What is the problem? Am I allowed to use Next.js routes like that with html extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with NextJS exporting files with .html extension but in<Link> there is no .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867105/how-to-deal-with-nextjs-exporting-files-with-html-extension-but-inlink-there)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the `pageExtensions` [option in nextJS -](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions)

I deployed a vercel app to show how this is working

https://html-ext.vercel.app/search-results.html

##### Steps

1. Add the `pageExtensions` to `next.config.js` files
   i.e

```
pageExtensions: ['html', 'jsx', 'js', 'tsx', 'ts'],
```

2. Rename the file under `pages` directory to `.html.js`  - `search-results.html.js` in this case.

Comment: Technically, you don't need to add `html` to `pageExtensions`. Simply having a file named `search-results.html.js` under the `pages` folder would work.

Comment: Not sure about js, it doesn't work with tsx files

Answer (score 0):

This naming convention `search-result.html` is not allowed for public sub-directories .
There are some ways of showing html file in next but I'm not sure they will work[check this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12373)

But you can easily copy everything inside your `<body>` tag inside your `Next js` project and it will work properly . How ever you have to manually add your `<meta>` and other head tags inside `Next js` built in `<Head/>` component .