# Next js dynamic route in production return 403 error but should return 404. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, next.js, production

When I try to go to `https://site.con/categories/` I receive `403 Forbidden`, but when I go to `https://site.con/categories/sport` everything fine, and else routes work fine. What could be the problem?

`pages/categories/[id].js`:

```
import { categories } from '../../data/categories';
import CategoryLayout from '../../layouts/CategoryLayout';

const Page = ({ category }) => {
  return <CategoryLayout data={category} />;
};
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: Object.keys(categories).map(category => ({
      params: {
        page: category
      }
    })),
    fallback: false
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const category = categories[params.id] || [];
  return {
    props: { category }
  };
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 2):

faced the same problem. Look at your server - you probably don't have index.html inside the /categories folder.

I've found the solution here: [How do I omit the html extension in next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866083/how-do-i-omit-the-html-extension-in-next-js)

adding

```
module.exports = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
}
```

would create physical folder for every route in /pages with index.html instead of the *route*.html

Hope it helps you!