# NextJS's Link works but converts them to .html when exported

Tags: next.js

This works :

```
<Link href="/about" passHref={true}><a className="hover:text-gray-400" rel="noreferrer">About</a></Link>
```

So when I run mydomain.com and click the About link, it goes to mydomain.com/about

But when I hard-refresh mydomain.com/about it returns 404 since the export has exported the file to mydomain.com/about.html - so how do I change the links to about.html in the  Link tag ? Because changing it to /about.html returns 404 in dev.

Comment: Does this link help> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62901065/13749957

Comment: I don't like the fact that `exportTrailingSlash: true,` created a folder with a single index.html in it for every route I have.

Comment: For now I have found a solution on a server that supports Rewrites like Apache's http. `RewriteRule ^about$ about.html`

Comment: I use an AWS lambda function to resolve the correct route. If you're using AWS and CloudFront, I can post the function.

Comment: Can you please let me know what the function is for AWS Lambda ? I have not yet tried AWS Lambda but am interested in it nevertheless.